# Command cd.. in Cygwin Terminal

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am using a Cygwin terminal and when I launch it, I can see that I am at:

```
/home/qi11091 (C:\cygwin64\home\qi11091)
```

But when I want to go to C:\ using the cd .. command I am stuck in C:\cygwin64, I can't go to C:\ .

Comment: The folder `C:\cygwin64` is your "/" (root) directory. You cannot go beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c: root is located at

```
/cygdrive/c/
```

As for the other drives

```
/cygdrive/d/
/cygdrive/e/
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @X.L.Ant , I'll mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

when you use cd in cygwin, it change your directory like Linux, instead of real path in Windows.

`/home/qi11091` is your home path, and it is linked to `C:\cygwin64\home\qi11091`in Windows.

when you use `cd ..`, it goes to /home, and it is linked to your `C:\cygwin64\home` in Windows.

then you use `cd ..` again, it goes to /, it is the root path of your system, and it is linked to your `C:\cygwin64` in Windows.

If you want to go to C:\, use `cd /cygdrive/c/`.